# Adding metadata (annotations) to python variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, type-hinting

I have a sqlalchemy class `User` which inherits from `Model`.

```py
class Model:
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(self):
        return self.__name__.lower()

    _id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    in_utc = Column(BigInteger, default=time())
    out_utc = Column(BigInteger, default=config['MAX_UTC'])

    def to_dict(self):
        return {k: v for k, v in vars(self).items() if not isinstance(v, InstanceState)}

class User(declarative_base(), Model):
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)
```

The reason for the parent class is to add some columns that are common across the tables and also the to_dict() method which creates a dictionary from the columns.

However I do not want the password column to be included when calling user.to_dict().

Is there any way to annotate the password Column (like in Java reflection) so that to_dict() knows to ignore it?

For example:

```py
class User(declarative_base(), Model):
    email = Column(String)

    [IgnoredInOutput()]
    password = Column(String)

    name = Column(String)
```

I've now overridden `to_dict` in the `User` class to remove the password column for this model.

Comment: I know this is not what you want, but still, `return {k: v for k, v in vars(self).items() if not isinstance(v, InstanceState) and k != 'password'}`

Comment: Don't store your password in plain text! Use a proper key derivation algorithm like [pbkdf2_hmac](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac) or [scrypt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.scrypt), with a per-user salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.9 introduced [`Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) Type Hints which can be used to decorate types with context-specific metadata.

`Annotated` takes at least two arguments. The first argument is a regular type (e.g. `str`, `int`, etc.), and the rest of the arguments is metadata. A type checker will only check the first argument, leaving the interpretation of the metadata to the application. A type hint like `Annotated[str, 'ignored']` will be treated equally to `str` by type checkers.

For example this will be a solutions with the new `Annotated` metadata:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, BigInteger
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.orm.state import InstanceState
from typing import Annotated, _AnnotatedAlias

Base = declarative_base()

class Model:
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(self):
        return self.__name__.lower()

    _id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    in_utc = Column(BigInteger)
    out_utc = Column(BigInteger)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {key: value for key, value in vars(self).items() if not isinstance(value, InstanceState) and key not in [var for var, th in self.__annotations__.items() if isinstance(th, _AnnotatedAlias) and 'ignored' in th.__metadata__]}

class User(Base, Model):
    email: str = Column(String)
    ignored: Annotated[str, 'ignored'] = Column(String)
    ignored_additional: Annotated[str, 'extra', 'ignored'] = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = User()
    user.name = "username"
    user.ignored = "ignored"
    user.ignored_additional = "ignored with additional metadata"
    user.email = "username@email.com"
    print(user.to_dict())
```

As you can see the type hints doesn't have to be included and normal type hints are also accepted without affecting the `to_dict` function. Also other metadata besides `ignored` can be added.